# Gradle build DeployApkTask.perform returns a NullPointerException

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I'm building an NDK project with gradle and I'm getting an error when Android Studio tries to put the apk onto my simulator. It reads out that gradle finished building the project, it just won't deploy to the simulator. Here is the error:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.DeployApkTask.perform(DeployApkTask.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

And my main `build.gradle`'s:

android/

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.0-alpha5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

android/app/

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0"
}

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        }

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = 'com.example.SanAngeles'
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel    = 11
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23

            buildConfigFields {
                create() {
                    type "int"
                    name "VALUE"
                    value "1"
                }
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "sanangeles"
            stl "stlport_static"
            CFlags.add("-I../../common/freetype/include")
            CFlags.add("-DANDROID_NDK")
            CFlags.add("-DDISABLE_IMPORTGL")
            CFlags.add("-DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY=1")
            ldLibs.add("EGL")
            ldLibs.add("android")
            ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
            ldLibs.add("dl")
            ldLibs.add("log")
            ldLibs.add("mui")
        }

        sources {
            main {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                    }
                }
                jni {
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDirs  = ["../../common/freetype/include"]
                        srcDirs += ["../../common/freetype/include/freetype"]
                        srcDirs += ["../../common/freetype/include/freetype/config"]
                    }
                    source {
                        srcDir "../../common/src"

                        include "../../common/freetype/src/autofit/autofit.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/basepic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftapi.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftbase.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftbbox.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftbitmap.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftdbgmem.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftdebug.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftglyph.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftinit.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftpic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftstroke.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftsynth.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/base/ftsystem.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/cff/cff.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pshinter/pshinter.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pshinter/pshglob.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pshinter/pshpic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pshinter/pshrec.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psnames/psnames.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psnames/pspic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/raster/raster.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/raster/rastpic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/pngshim.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/sfntpic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttbdf.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttkern.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttload.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttmtx.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttpost.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttsbit.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/sfobjs.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/ttcmap.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/sfnt/sfdriver.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/smooth/smooth.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/smooth/ftspic.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/truetype/truetype.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type1/t1driver.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/cid/cidgload.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/cid/cidload.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/cid/cidobjs.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/cid/cidparse.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/cid/cidriver.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pfr/pfr.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pfr/pfrgload.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pfr/pfrload.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pfr/pfrobjs.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pfr/pfrsbit.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type42/t42objs.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type42/t42parse.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type42/type42.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/winfonts/winfnt.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pcf/pcfread.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pcf/pcfutil.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/pcf/pcfdrivr.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psaux/afmparse.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psaux/psaux.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psaux/psconv.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psaux/psobjs.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/psaux/t1decode.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/tools/apinames.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type1/t1afm.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type1/t1gload.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type1/t1load.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type1/t1objs.c"
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/type1/t1parse."
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/bdf/bdfdrivr."
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/bdf/bdflib."
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip."
                        include "../../common/freetype/src/lzw/ftlzw.c"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what it is going on, but I worked around it by downgrading from `0.8.0-alpha5` to  `0.8.0-alpha4`.